# How to insert a string in to a string where i find a substring , using SED

Tags: string, sed, insert, append, substring

```
$ cat f1
My name is Bruce and my surname is
```

I want to use SED to find “Bruce” and then append “ Lee” to the end of the line in which “Bruce” is found

Then a more tricky one….
I want to INSERT ….a string… in to a line in which I find sometihng.
So example

```
$ cat f2
My name is Yacov and I am from Israel.
I used to be a programmer but then I found love for a woman who told me to become a teacher.
```

I want to use SED to insert the string “ excellent ” where I find the string “programmer”.
I want to insert this string exactly in beginning of the substring “programmer”

Comment: We are not here to be your tutors, or write code for you. You show what you have written, we (maybe) try to help fix it.

Comment: The man page isn't great to learn from, but did you check out [this tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)? Also recommended: [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922259.do).

Comment: Benjamin W, I have seen that page and also one about AWK and wow it is really powerful but you need to know how to understand what they are saying. I am not about to follow all the usage examples they show. For example, they show you the usage of append for, but they write it as if you were using it in a bash file. I have managed to successfully implement the examples so i am obviously not doing that poorly. I just struggle to perform some of them on a single line in the command prompt though.

Comment: Benjamin W,  I also follow the append example using SED but it appends the string to the line below in t the file u are editing. So im my case i am finding the string i want and then at the end of that line i want to append a string. It appends the string but to the new line. I assume that is absolutely correct using the "a" option. I however want to know how to append on the same line in which i find a string i am searching for.

Comment: Benjamin W ,  My next challenge is to insert a string at the beginning or the end of a string i find in a text file (which i have found and tried the I option also but it is replacing and over writing the rest of the line which i dont want).

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried this?

```
$ cat f1
My name is Bruce and my surname is
$ sed 's/^.*Bruce.*$/& Lee/' f1
My name is Bruce and my surname is Lee
$ cat f2
My name is Yacov and I am from Israel.
I used to be a programmer but then I found love for a woman who told me
to become a teacher.
$ sed 's/programmer/excellent programmer/' f2
My name is Yacov and I am from Israel.
I used to be a excellent programmer but then I found love for a woman 
who told me to become a teacher.
```